# Extra cell/text over the hline in a table

Tags: tables

Is it possible to add text on a coloured background or a cell to the middle of a line (similar to the image)? Thank you

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{multirow}

\textwidth 18cm
\textheight 26cm
\hoffset -1cm
\voffset -3cm
\oddsidemargin 0cm
\evensidemargin 0cm

\def\displayskip{\vskip6pt\relax}
\def\enddisplayskip{\vskip7pt\relax}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begingroup
\centering
\rowcolors{3}{white}{gray!20}
\def\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|r|r|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}l|}
\hline
          &      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{A}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{A}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{B}}  & \\
\hhline{~~|------|~}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{A}}   & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{B}}     & {\textbf{B}} & {\textbf{B}}  & \textbf{other} & \textbf{A}   & \textbf{A} & \textbf{A} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{B}} \\
\hline
     AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
     AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\

\hline
     AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
     AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
\hline
     AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
     AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\par
\endgroup
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the advice:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\textwidth 18cm
\textheight 26cm
\hoffset -1cm
\voffset -3cm
\oddsidemargin 0cm
\evensidemargin 0cm
\def\displayskip{\vskip6pt\relax}
\def\enddisplayskip{\vskip7pt\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{rr*{6}{X[c]}l}[color-inside,vlines]
  \Hline
  \Block{2-1}{\textbf{A}} &  \Block{2-1}{\textbf{B}}    & \Block{1-2}{\textbf{A}}  && \Block{1-2}{\textbf{A}} &&
  \Block{1-2}{\textbf{B}}  && \Block{2-1}{\textbf{B}} \\
  \Hline
  &  & {\textbf{B}} & {\textbf{B}}  & \textbf{other} & \textbf{A}   & \textbf{A} & \textbf{A} & \\
  \Hline
  \rowcolors{gray!20}{}
       AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
       AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\

  \Hline
       AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
       AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
  \Hline
       AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
       AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
  \Hline
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (3-|1) [fill=yellow!50,right] { \small text} ; 
  \node at (5-|1) [fill=yellow!50,right] { \small text} ; 
  \node at (7-|1) [fill=yellow!50,right] { \small text} ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error: Package nicematrix Error: Unknown key. for the line: \begin{NiceTabular}{rr*{6}{X[c]}l}[color-inside,vlines]

Comment: You probably don't have the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation (MiKTeX, TeXLive, etc.).

Comment: If you use Overleaf, you should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Thank you. I added a figure to my question. Did you mean that, please?

Comment: Yes. With the file `nicematrix.sty` uploaded, it should work. I have tried on Overleaf : [here](https://fr.overleaf.com/read/nnngvmmkmfxj#92a8bf)

Comment: Thank you very, very much, it works.

Answer (score 2):

With older version of `NiceMatrix`

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\textwidth 18cm
\textheight 26cm
\hoffset -1cm
\voffset -3cm
\oddsidemargin 0cm
\evensidemargin 0cm
\def\displayskip{\vskip6pt\relax}
\def\enddisplayskip{\vskip7pt\relax}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \def\arraystretch{1.4}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{r*{7}{X[c]}l}
            \CodeBefore
            \rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{white!10}[respect-blocks]
            \Body
            \Hline
            \Block{2-1}{\textbf{A}} &  \Block{2-1}{\textbf{B}}    & \Block{1-2}{\textbf{A}}  && \Block{1-2}{\textbf{A}} &&
            \Block{1-2}{\textbf{B}}  && \Block{2-1}{\textbf{B}} \\
            \Hline
            &  & {\textbf{B}} & {\textbf{B}}  & \textbf{other} & \textbf{A}   & \textbf{A} & \textbf{A} & \\
            \Hline
        
            AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
            AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
            
            \Hline
            AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
            AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
            \Hline
            AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
            AAAAAA &   B & C  & D & E & F &  G &  -  & H \\
            \Hline
            \CodeAfter
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node at (3-|1) [fill=yellow!50,right] { \small text} ; 
                \node at (5-|1) [fill=yellow!50,right] { \small text} ; 
                \node at (7-|1) [fill=yellow!50,right] { \small text} ; 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for me, but I need the alternating colours of rows and lines as in my question.